# android onLocationChanged set fastest frequency

Tags: android, android-ndk, gps, location, driver

I develop application, which needs to get location updates as fast as possible and only from GPS (not from network). 
I've requested to get the location updates as frequently, as possible by this:

```
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; 
 private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; 
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
```

Unfortunately, the updates come only every 10 seconds, and I need to make is 30 times faster (this is the requirement of my algoritm).
Is there any way to achive that? I suppose I need to configure it at lower level (maybe in native code? ). And also probably I shoul read the location not from the android API, but from another, lower level. The question is how?
I would appreciate your advice

Comment: And of course I've implemented the onLocationChanged. The update frequency on once in 10 seconds is from the onLocationChanged callback.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using GPS_Provider. Try using Network_Provider which gives faster access to locations.

Also implement onLocationChanged method in your program which will be called whenever the location changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm using GPS_Provider, because it is more precise than the network and more expectable. The output of the network provider can be less consistent. And of course I've implemented the onLocationChanged. The update frequency on once in 10 seconds is from the onLocationChanged callback.

Comment: So the question remains the same. How can I improve the frequency of the  GPS_Provider? Maybe there is a way to get the location updates not via onLocationChanged?

Comment: Yeh, I've tested also the google maps api (using the fused locatiob provider). It gave me update once a second. I need 3 times faster(((

Answer (score -1):

I have noticed that if I start my basic GPS location app activity afresh each time I get quicker updates rather than forcing a call to updatelocation. Can you confirm if you get similar  behaviour.

Comment: You should comment the OP's question, because this is not an answer yet